# pandas dataframe split values in one row by weights

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, weighted

this seems like a basic question,  but an elegant solution is escaping me.

I have a pandas dataframe where all the values have been assigned into one row.  However, I need to split values across multiple rows by weights. Example here:

Input dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# starting df with weights W.
df_input = pd.DataFrame({
    'W': [0.3, 0.2, 0.5],
    'X1': [100, 0, 0],
    'X2': [150, 0, 0],
    'X3': [200, 0, 0],
    'X4': [300, 0, 0]
})
```

The desired output dataframe:

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame({
    'W': [0.3, 0.2, 0.5],
    'X1': [30, 20, 50],
    'X2': [45, 30, 75],
    'X3': [60, 40, 100],
    'X4': [90, 60, 150]
})
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure-pandas solution:

```
df_output = df_input.copy()
df_output.loc[:, 'X1':] = df_output.loc[:, 'X1':].apply(lambda col: col[0] * df_output['W'])
```

Or using numpy broadcasting:

```
df_output = df_input.copy()
df_output.loc[:, 'X1':] = df_output.loc[0, 'X1':].values[None, :] * df_output['W'].values[:, None]
```

Comment: This does not distribute the values through the zeros - so the product does not yield what  the output was looking for.  If you add a `max(col)` then it works nicely!

Comment: This worked for the first row with W=0.3,  but X1:X4 were still 0's for the other rows in df_output.

Comment: Thanks - it works.   Up voting this one as the solution,  though i learned from each of the other answers too.

Comment: even better to use the first index to get the max value. +1

Answer (score 1):

Elegant is subjective - A possible way is to use `pd.clip`

```
 for col in ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4']:
     df_input[col] = df_input[col].clip(lower=df_input[col].max())
     df_input[col]*=df_input['W']
```

The result will be the above.

Comment: In my subjective opinion,  this was elegant! :)  Its a creative way to use clip.  This has some advantages vs. using fill,  as it does not assume the first row is the one that caries the values to be weighted.  Thanks for the post!

Answer (score 1):

Using `DataFrame.ffill` to fill the values in your column, then multiply them by the factors with `DataFrame.multiply`

```
values = df_input.replace(0, np.NaN).ffill()
df_input.iloc[:, 1:] = values.iloc[:, 1:].mul(df_input['W'], axis=0)
```

Or we can make use of `numpy`, but first we have to reshape our array to `(,1)`

```
values = df_input.replace(0, np.NaN).ffill()
df_input.iloc[:, 1:] = values.iloc[:, 1:] * values['W'].to_numpy()[:, None]

     W    X1    X2     X3     X4
0  0.3  30.0  45.0   60.0   90.0
1  0.2  20.0  30.0   40.0   60.0
2  0.5  50.0  75.0  100.0  150.0
```

Comment: With so many nice answers its hard to choose.  I like this one too.  Thanks for taking the time to reply!

Answer (score 1):

## Output the data to `numpy` arrays, then calculate the dot product

- Create two arrays from from the row and column data
- Shape the arrays
- `np.dot` the two arrays

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# using your data

# weight
w = df_input.iloc[:, 0].to_numpy().reshape(len(df_input), 1)

array([[0.3],
       [0.2],
       [0.5]])

# values
v = df_input.iloc[0, 1:].to_numpy().reshape(1, len(df_input.columns[1:]))

array([[30., 45., 60., 90.]])

# load dot product into a dataframe
df_out = pd.DataFrame(np.dot(w, v))

# add column names
df_out.columns = df_input.columns[1:]

# insert W if needed
df_out.insert(0, 'W', df_input['W'])

# output
   W    X1    X2     X3     X4
 0.3  30.0  45.0   60.0   90.0
 0.2  20.0  30.0   40.0   60.0
 0.5  50.0  75.0  100.0  150.0
```

Comment: I like this solution too.  Very logical and easy to follow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to the excellent answers already provided:

Get the x only columns :

```
x_columns = df_input.filter(like='X').columns
```

Compute (explanations embedded in the comments):

```
df_input.loc[:,x_columns] = (df_input.loc[:,x_columns]
                            #spill the non zero values downwards
                            .replace(0,method='ffill')
                            #multiply by the 'W' column
                            .mul(df_input['W'],axis=0)
                            .astype(int)
                            )


     W  X1  X2  X3  X4
0   0.3 30  45  60  90
1   0.2 20  30  40  60
2   0.5 50  75  100 150
```

Comment: Nice!   I like this too.  Note that methods using ffill will require a sort if the non zeros row is not first (perhaps I should have made the 2nd row the one with values :).   Bonus points for exact match (even adding the cast to int! - though I don't need that).  Thanks for you answer!

Comment: yea, thanks for the feedback on the sort angle. we share ideas here, that's part of the thrill

Answer (score -2):

If i understand correctly, this is just a simple matrix multiplication.
Where you start with a (3,1) matrix and you multiple by a (1,3).
The end result would be a (3,3). Let me know if this kinda workaround helps in any way:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[3,6,7],[5,-3,0]])
B = np.array([[1,1],[2,1],[3,-1]])
C = A.dot(B)
print (C)

Output:
[[36,-12],
 [-1,  2]
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the post.  Since it did not match the input and output,  I did not upvote it.  However,  It did put me on the right track,  as others noted - using the dot product was a good clue.